# Just joined, answered one question, got a badge--is that unusual?

Tags: discussion, badges, new-users

So, after lurking for some time, I finally registered an account today. Then I gave someone a brief answer (which I didn't think was particularly insightful), and got a bronze "Teacher" badge. Just wondering how meaningful that is. Does everyone get badges quickly when they start participating?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, well... you're *supposed* to. In fact, you can get the [Autobiographer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/9/autobiographer) badge just by completing all your profile fields - no real participation on the site is required at all. Same goes for the [Informed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/2600/informed) badge, which is awarded for reading all of the about page.

See, badges are meant to encourage positive behavior and, especially with the bronze badges, **teach you how to use the site**. Everyone loves badges, and we know that. So what better way to get users familiar with the different features they can use than to give them a badge for just *using* them?